# Why isn't "a single + noun" a tautological repeat?

Tags: word-usage

By definition,

> **single** means
>   (1) : consisting of or having only one part, feature, or portion
>
> (2) : consisting of one as opposed to or in contrast with many
>
> (3) : consisting of only one in number
>
> by Merriam-Webster

So why do we still say

> "a single rose"
>
> "hold to a single ideal"

Not

> "single rose"
>
> "hold to single ideal"

Comment: Consider that just because something is a "tautological repeat" doesn't mean it's bad English or ungrammatical. Repetition is used *a lot* in language; there is no requirement to always make the simplest statement.

Comment: "A tautological repeat" is a tautology.

Answer (score 22):

Repetition can be used for emphasis.

The indefinite article "a" does imply that there is only one [thing](otherwise you would normally use no article and a plural noun). So maybe you could say "single" is redundant in some sentences. But people do use it for emphasis when they want to make an explicit point that there is *only* one [thing].

Perhaps the word "single" could be left out in some situations, but the article "a" is a feature of the language, and you can't leave that word out (as you seem to suggest.) If you feel "a single" is repetitive, then leave out the "single". The "a" isn't optional.

Comment: When doesn't the use of "a" imply that there is only one thing? I can't think of anything off the top of my head.

Comment: @Taelsin "A person should be clear when communicating." doesn't imply that there is only one person.

Comment: No, but it implies that you are only *talking* about one person at a time. And the fact you don't make any other qualifications on "person" means it might be *any* person. So if you want to get picky, "A person should..." is effectively the same as, "People should....", but you are taking the people one at a time: "Each one should....."

Comment: @Taelsin, if someone asks "Is there a doctor in the house?" and you are there with two doctors, you don't answer "no".

Comment: @ThePhoton Perhaps I worded my question incorrectly, or perhaps it's just not clicking for me. While I agree that if someone were to ask "Is there a doctor here?" the correct answer would be "yes" if there were one or more doctors, the question is still only asking for one doctor even if multiple exist. Perhaps my question should have been: When is the indefinite article "a" used with a plural noun and not a singular noun?

Comment: And now reading my question and the answer again, I can't for the life of me understand why I asked that question... Don't mind me...

Answer (score 20):

**Single** serves the same role here that any other adjective would do, whether we are talking about a single rose, a solitary rose, a red rose or any other rose.

Introducing an adjective to qualify the rose does not change the need for the article **a** (or **the**)

The role of **single** is to emphasise that there are no other roses, not to replace the article.

It makes the difference between statements such as:

> **a pupil raised her hand**
>   and
>   **a single pupil raised her hand**.

The adjective changes the nuance. The emphasis moves from the raising of the hand to the fact that only a single pupil does so. The same is true for saying **a rose stood in the vase** and **a single rose stood in the vase**.

The same rule applies regardless of whether you are talking about a rose, an ideal or any other noun.

Comment: Exactly. If I say "there was a problem", it does not mean there was only one ("a" could be interpreted as "one among other"). If I said "there was a single problem" it becomes unique. So basically the language is too ambiguous to infer "a" is redundant with "single".

Answer (score 6):

We can say things like "six single roses" to mean something like *six roses, but none of them grouped together*.  Since there's nothing redundant about "six single roses", there's nothing redundant about "one single rose" or "a single rose".

It's hard to describe the meaning of "single" without using the word "one".  However, that doesn't mean that the adjective "single" is a good determiner.  We use some other word to fill the determiner role when that role is appropriate:  a single rose, the single rose, this single rose, whichever single rose, and so on.

Comment: Roses (and other species of flowers) might be a confusing  example here, because "single rose" or "double rose" refers to the number and arrangement of petals in different types of flower. "Double" flowers have twice as many petals as "single" flowers.

Answer (score 0):

Just because the meanings of two words overlap, that doesn't mean they are redundant. "single" is adjective that merely indicates singularity. "a" is an article that indicates singularity and indefiniteness, and is a determiner. So "single" provides only one out of three of the roles of "a". You can also say "the single rose", and that would mean something different from "a single rose", so "a" adds meaning.